# What is the practical difference between `git rm --cached`, `git reset --` and `git reset HEAD` to unstage changes?

Tags: git

I have an alias, `unstage`, to remove changes from the staging area.

```
unstage = reset --
```

I've noticed git's help suggests `git reset HEAD` instead. I've also noticed that `git rm --cached` will do the same thing.

With the exception that `git rm --cached` will not clear the whole stage without `-r`, is there a practical difference between these techniques to remove changes from the staging area? By practical I mean can you show a scenario where they would produce different results? Or can I safely use them interchangeably?

Comment: Well, one obvious difference between `git reset --` and `git reset HEAD` is that you'll get an error (`ambiguous argument 'HEAD': both revision and filename`) if you try to run the latter with a file named `HEAD` in your staging area. Are you really asking about the difference between `git reset --`, `git reset HEAD --`, and `git rm --cached --`?

Comment: @Jubobs The practical issue is choosing what to use for "unstage", your point is interesting and worth an answer. It's also from curiosity if I'm missing something subtle.

Comment: *The practical issue is choosing what to use for "unstage" [...]* I remember trying to come up with a nice `unstage` alias, but I gave up. I don't think there is a way of catering for all the possible cases (file changes, file additions, file renames, file deletions) in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

git reset is the **proper** way to unstage, now here's why:

First let's clarify a few things:
If no commit is provided git defaults commit to HEAD

```
git reset == git reset HEAD
```

As for the -- it expects a path after it.

Now, for the difference between:

```
git reset --mixed AND git rm --cached
```

(reset defaults to --mixed)

```
git reset --mixed
           Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for
           commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action.

git rm --cached
       Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or
       not, will be left alone.enter code here
```

Essentially the difference being here, git rm --cached actually puts specified files into untracked, and stages their removal for the next commit.
Git reset --mixed, on the other hand, simply moves the file into 'unstaged', but keeps its old version in repo.

Comment: The question is not about the "proper" way, it's about whether there are demonstrable differences. That `git rm --cached` will delete an existing file from staging is a good one. As for the two `reset`s, paths to `git reset --` are also optional and both will unstage all files, so I don't see a difference.

Comment: @Tomasz `git reset` is not strictly equivalent to `git reset HEAD`; see my other [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004187/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-git-rm-cached-git-reset-and#comment53838268_33004187).

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks, I haven't thought about that at all.

Comment: Note that as of Git 2.23, the new `git restore` command has been added to do this. The output of `git status` will recommend `(use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)`

Comment: Do you mean "unstage" when you say "onstage"?

Comment: @GordonBai: I believe this is was a typo. Coming back to haunt me 6 years later. :)

Comment: Unbelievable how time flies! I was an undergraguate back then

Answer (score 6):

The difference (not considering things like confusing pathnames with ref names) is like this:

- `git reset [<tree-ish>] path [path...]` would take the value of `<tree-ish>` (which defaults to `HEAD` if omitted) and make sure *the index* entry for the specified path looks exactly like it's recorded in that `<tree-ish>`, that is:

  - If it has contents recorded as blob `a398bc837d`, the index entry will refer to that blob as well.
  - If no entry by that name exists, it will be deleted from the index.
- `git rm --cached path [path ...]`, on the other hand, *removes* and entry matching `path` from the index.

As you can see, the difference manifests itself in this case:

1. Your `HEAD` already contains an entry for the file `foo.txt`.
2. You `git add` a change to `foo.txt` from the work tree.
3. Now

   - `git reset [HEAD] foo.txt` would revert the contents of `foo.txt` recorded in the index to the contents this file has in the `HEAD`.
   - `git rm --cached foo.txt` would remove the entry for the `foo.txt` from the index.

As you can see, should you now commit, the contents of the next commit will either have or not have `foo.txt` -- depending on what you've done.

To sum this up, unstaging is only done via `git reset HEAD` — it's an opposite to `git add`.

To put it in another perspective:

- `git add pathname` adds *changes* the `pathname` contains in the work tree compared to its state in the index.  If `pathname` does not exist in the index at all, an entry for it is first created.  Do you see the fine difference?
- Being reverse to `git add`, `git reset HEAD` would remove *the change* added by `git add`: if you `git add`-ed a change over an already existing index entry, its original contents will be restored in the index. If it did not exist in the index at all, it will be removed.

  Conversely to this, `git rm --cached` removes an entry unconditionally.  So it "cancels" a `git add` operation only in the case where `git add` *created* that index entry you're trying nuke using `git rm --cached`.

Comment: That covers `git rm` vs `git reset` well, what about `git reset HEAD` vs `git reset --`? Confusing path names with ref names is important, I don't want to go to unstage a file and instead have it do something else.

Comment: @Schwern, it's a red herring. The `--` argument is a long-established *policy* which tells the program "treat the following arguments verbatim, no matter if they look like options". So it can be used to reset an entry named, say, `--hard` even if it looks like an option name.

Comment: @Schwern, as to what exact spelling to use for your alias, the rule of thumb is simple: use the least ambiguous (or the more precise) form possible. That is, spell it in full: `git reset HEAD --` - this would remove any possible ambiguity when the macro gets substituted.

Comment: @Schwern, in case it's not clear from the docs, if you omit that `<three-ish>` from the call it defaults to `HEAD` but then again see my other comment.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I know about the `--` convention. It's odd that the `git-reset` docs treat `git reset --` and `git reset HEAD` as separate commands with separate options.

Comment: @Schwern, I read the docs differently than you. We're talking about the first form of calling `git reset`, and it's defined in the manual like this: `git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>...` with that `<tree-ish>` being an optional specification of a tree object to use. `HEAD` is just one possible "something" which can be resolved to a `<tree-ish>` (because a commit always references a single tree object), and it's used by default if this argument is omitted. So, no, no seapare commands with separate options -- please read the man page closely.

Comment: It's bad docs if I have to "read it closely". The docs list different options for the two styles. `git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]` vs `git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>...` implies that `<mode>` can't be used with the `--` form, or `-q` can't be used with the `git reset --` form, but they can. I see what they're trying to do, separating working with the index from moving around HEAD, but the docs listing them as separate "forms" with separate options implies there's a fundamental difference between `git reset <commit>` and `git reset --`.

Comment: @Schwern, well, I suggest you to read [this essay](https://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html) to better grasp the various modes of `git reset`. As to docs, documentation patches and suggestions for them *are* welcomed [on the official list](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#git). I occasionally see both the doco patches and discussions about the ways to improve the docs there. So please consider sharing your doubts using that venue.

Answer (score 3):

**I'm going to answer what is the difference between `git rm --staged <file>` and `git reset HEAD <file>`**

**Both can be used when a person wants to remove a file from the staging area.**

With `git rm --staged`, a person can remove the file for the particular commit where he doesn't want the changes to come. And then after the commit `git add` it and commit it again.

With `git reset`, a person can remove the changes to the file for the particular commit where he doesn't want his changes to come. And then after the commit `git add` it and commit it again.

**But both are very different in terms of what actually happens.**

With `git rm --staged some-file`, the file gets removed from the staging area and is not tracked anymore. The file will still be in the working area. Commit the changes with the file being removed with `git rm --staged`. Add the file with `git add` and commit the changes again. Now go back to where the file was removed, you'll notice that the file doesn't show up at all in the directory. It's missing. This can cause problems if other code depends on this file.

With `git reset HEAD some-file`, the changes done to the file since the last commit get removed from the staging area but the file is still being tracked. So when you go back to the commit where you ran `git reset HEAD some-file.txt`, the file will be still there but the changes will not be there.

For unstaging a file, `git reset HEAD <file>` should be used.

Comment: Thanks! I certainly misused the command. But what I don't get: when it's safer to use `git reset` why does git itself show the following tip for the staged files when doing `git status`: `(use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)`

Answer (score 1):

`git rm --cached <file>` **unstages and untracks** (marked for removal on next commit) a given file, while `git reset HEAD <file>` just **unstages** the file

Answer (score 1):

## Brief answer:

To unstage **all** changes from the staging area, use the `git reset` command without specifying any files or paths like:

```
 git reset
```

This will move all your changes from the staging area to the working area.

I personally use this command frequently as it is safe.

For unstaging a particular file,

```
git reset HEAD <file>
```

---

## Detailed answer `git reset` vs `git rm -r --cached` .?

### git reset

The `git reset` is a git command that resets your head to the last commit.

`git reset` has 3 operating modes:

1. Hard
2. Soft
3. Mixed

**Default Operating Mode:**`git reset --mixed` is the default operating mode.

Let's focus here on `mixed` mode for other [modes in reset.](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-reset).

In this mode, the ref pointers are updated. The staging index is reset to the state of the specified commit. Any changes that have been undone from the Staging Index are moved to the working directory.

### git rm -r --cached

Firstly, we need to understand what `git rm` does and how it works. It removes a file from the **working directory and from the index**, and when you commit, the file is removed from the tree as well.

`git rm --cached`, however, removes the file from the **index alone and keeps it in your working copy**.

If you have some files that are previously committed and you want to remove them from your current staging area. You can also use this command to remove those files from your current working area and index and make them new untracked files.

When `git add` is used to add a new (previously untracked) file, then `git rm --cached` is the exact opposite of `git add`